# R foreach function cannot find counter with souce function

Tags: r, foreach

I'm trying to use foreach for my project and I kept getting an error says that the iteration counter for the foreach cannot be found. Here is my code.

```
library(doSNOW)
a=20
seed=10
cl=makeCluster(4,type="SOCK",outfile="")
clusterExport(cl,"a")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
x=foreach(i=1:100,.combine="c",.multicombine=T) %dopar% {
  print(i)
  set.seed(seed+i)
  source("d:\\play\\foreach source.r")
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

The "foreach source.r" code is the following:

```
rnorm(1e5)+a+i
```

And below is the error I got:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'i' not found"
```

Dose anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the local argument in source:

```
library(doSNOW)
a=20
seed=10
cl=makeCluster(4,type="SOCK",outfile="")
clusterExport(cl,"a")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
x=foreach(i=1:100,.combine="c",.multicombine=T) %dopar% {
  print(i)
  set.seed(seed+i)
  source("d:\\play\\foreach source.r", local = TRUE) # <---- HERE
}
stopCluster(cl)
```